# IE8 Z-Index Position Absolute

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have an anchor within a div overlaying all the contents of the div. The problem is that IE8 is ignoring the link when you hover over any non-white-space (e.g. an image or some text): http://jsfiddle.net/jf7xf/

What CSS do I need to apply to what elements to make IE8 have the anchor overlay any sibling elements?

Comment: I.E., the thorn in so many sides...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, I have found that to overlay the anchor in IE8 I have to place an image into the anchor. I have used a 1x1 transparent pixel, set the width and height as 100% and it works! Yay!

http://jsfiddle.net/jf7xf/44/